# Issues with images, security and cache

Tags: html, ajax, amazon-s3

I've got some issues regarding images and secure access to the cloud (S3, in this case).
I do want to have direct access to avoid stressing my server so I do have two options:

1.) Generate a signed url on my server and send it back to client to load from
2.) Generate an Authorization-Header sent within the request from the client

Now, 1. & 2. work just fine, however, I am in trouble regarding images in html.
For 1.), images will be re-requested each time as the url changes every time and thus renders caching useless.
For 2.), caching would work as the url'd stay constant though I've seeked the net to figure how to add a custom http request header to image request including my security token without luck.

So, what options are left for me? How do others resolve that issue?

thanks
Alex

Comment: S3 Doesn't support cookies or did I miss something?

Comment: Never mind than. I did not realized that you are not serving images yourself... (And yes, 2 is impossible with GET requests send by browsers).